# Parallel algorithm to sum-assign the elements of a vector to the elements of another one

Tags: c++, c++17, stl-algorithm

Consider:

```
std::vector<double> u, v;

#pragma omp parallel for
for (std::size_t i = 0u; i < u.size(); ++i)
  u[i] += v[i];
```

To express similar code with the C++17 parallel algorithms, the solution I found so far is to use the two input ranges version of `std::transform`:

```
std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq,
               std::begin(u), std::end(u), std::begin(v), std::begin(u),
               std::plus())
```

which I don't like at all because it bypasses the `+=` operator of my types and in my real use case leads to much more verbose (4 times longer) code than the original OpenMP code (I cannot just use `std::plus` because I have to first make an operation on the RHS range elements).

Is there another algorithm that I oversight?

Note also that if I use `ranges::zip` the code won't run in parallel in GCC 9 because if `iterator_category` is not at least `forward_iterator` the PSTL back-end falls back to the sequential algorithm: https://godbolt.org/z/XGtPwc.

Comment: @George Yes. In my real code I need to use a lambda. That's part of the extra verbosity I don't like.

Comment: @George Compare `for (std::size_t i = 0u; i < u.size(); ++i)
  u[i] += 2 * v[i];` with `std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq, std::begin(u), std::end(u), std::begin(v), std::begin(u), [](auto a, auto b) { return a + 2 * b })`

Comment: @metalfox: You are unlikely to find another algorithm which is concise than the one you have now. Any algorithm will require at least the four iterators, the scheduling policy and a function object as arguments.

Comment: Using functions from the algorithm header often results in more verbose code. The benefit is in the correctness of the implementation.

Comment: @George They are general so you can use their correctness in any situation.

Comment: @P.W I see. Does that also mean that it is not possible to use the `+=` operator?

Comment: AFAIK nothing in `<algorithm>` uses compound assignments, it's only ever copy (or move) assignments

Comment: Also AFAIK  `std::for_each` is the only thing in `<algorithm>` that allows modification through it's input range.

Comment: @George it's UB to modify the parameters passed to the functor in `std::transform`

Comment: @Caleth Yes. I considered the `for_each` option. The problem is that I would need either proxy or stashing iterators, which don’t work in the GCC parallel algorithms (unless I specialize their `iterator_traits` myself). That’s unfortunate because there are non-trivial types that would benefit from using `+=` instead of the chained sum and then assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried tbb::zip_iterator (https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/iterators/zip_iterator.html)?
Its `iterator_category` is `random_access_iterator`.

So the code will look like

```
auto zip_begin = tbb::make_zip_iterator(std::begin(u), std::begin(v));
std::for_each(par_unseq, zip_begin, zip_begin + u.size(),
                  [](auto &&x) { std::get<0u>(x) += std::get<1u>(x); });
```

Comment: That's great! Happy to help