# Different assembly when rangifying a simple algorithm

Tags: c++, c++17, range-v3

When I was preparing supplementary info for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56128455/parallel-algorithm-to-sum-assign-the-elements-of-a-vector-to-the-elements-of-ano), I noticed that “rangified” implementations of a very simple algorithm resulted in important differences (to my eyes) in the resulting assembly, compared with “legacy” implementations.

I expanded the tests a bit, with the following results (GCC 9.1 -O3):

- **Case 1. Simple for loop (https://godbolt.org/z/rAVaT2)**

  ```
   #include <vector>

   void foo(std::vector<double> &u, std::vector<double> const &v)
   {
     for (std::size_t i = 0u; i < u.size(); ++i)
       u[i] += v[i];
   }
  ```

```
        mov rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov rdi, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        sub rdi, rdx
        sar rdi, 3
        je .L1
        mov rcx, QWORD PTR [rsi]
        lea rax, [rcx+15]
        sub rax, rdx
        cmp rax, 30
        jbe .L7
        lea rax, [rdi-1]
        cmp rax, 1
        jbe .L7
        mov rsi, rdi
        xor eax, eax
        shr rsi
        sal rsi, 4
        .L4:
        movupd xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rcx+rax]
        movupd xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+rax]
        addpd xmm0, xmm1
        movups XMMWORD PTR [rdx+rax], xmm0
        add rax, 16
        cmp rsi, rax
        jne .L4
        mov rsi, rdi
        and rsi, -2
        and edi, 1
        je .L1
        lea rax, [rdx+rsi*8]
        movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax]
        addsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rcx+rsi*8]
        movsd QWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
        ret
        .L7:
        xor eax, eax
        .L3:
        movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx+rax*8]
        addsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rcx+rax*8]
        movsd QWORD PTR [rdx+rax*8], xmm0
        add rax, 1
        cmp rdi, rax
        jne .L3
        .L1:
        ret
```

- **Case 2. `std::transform` (https://godbolt.org/z/2iZaqo)**

  ```
  #include <algorithm>
  #include <vector>

  void foo(std::vector<double> &u, std::vector<double> const &v)
  {
  std::transform(std::begin(u), std::end(u),
                 std::begin(v),
                 std::begin(u),
                 std::plus());
  }
  ```

```
        mov rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        mov rsi, QWORD PTR [rsi]
        cmp rax, rdx
        je .L1
        sub rax, 8
        lea rcx, [rsi+15]
        sub rax, rdx
        sub rcx, rdx
        shr rax, 3
        cmp rcx, 30
        jbe .L7
        movabs rcx, 2305843009213693950
        test rax, rcx
        je .L7
        lea rcx, [rax+1]
        xor eax, eax
        mov rdi, rcx
        shr rdi
        sal rdi, 4
        .L4:
        movupd xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+rax]
        movupd xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax]
        addpd xmm0, xmm1
        movups XMMWORD PTR [rdx+rax], xmm0
        add rax, 16
        cmp rax, rdi
        jne .L4
        mov rdi, rcx
        and rdi, -2
        lea rax, [0+rdi*8]
        add rdx, rax
        add rsi, rax
        cmp rcx, rdi
        je .L1
        movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx]
        addsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi]
        movsd QWORD PTR [rdx], xmm0
        ret
        .L7:
        xor ecx, ecx
        .L3:
        movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx+rcx*8]
        addsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+rcx*8]
        mov rdi, rcx
        movsd QWORD PTR [rdx+rcx*8], xmm0
        add rcx, 1
        cmp rax, rdi
        jne .L3
        .L1:
        ret
```

- **Case 3. Range-v3 `view::zip` (https://godbolt.org/z/0BEkfT)**

  ```
  #define RANGES_ASSERT(...) ((void)0)

  #include <algorithm>
  #include <range/v3/view/zip.hpp>
  #include <vector>

  void foo(std::vector<double> &u, std::vector<double> const &v)
  {
  auto w = ranges::view::zip(u, v);

  std::for_each(std::begin(w), std::end(w),
                [](auto &&x) { std::get<0u>(x) += std::get<1u>(x); });
  }
  ```

```
        mov rdx, QWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov rsi, QWORD PTR [rsi+8]
        mov rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov rcx, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        cmp rdx, rsi
        je .L1
        cmp rax, rcx
        je .L1
        .L3:
        movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax]
        addsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx]
        add rax, 8
        add rdx, 8
        movsd QWORD PTR [rax-8], xmm0
        cmp rax, rcx
        je .L1
        cmp rdx, rsi
        jne .L3
        .L1:
        ret
```

- **Case 4. cmcstl2 `ranges::transform` (https://godbolt.org/z/MjYO1G)**

  ```
  #include <experimental/ranges/algorithm>
  #include <vector>

  namespace std
  {
  namespace ranges = experimental::ranges;
  }

  void foo(std::vector<double> &u,s td::vector<double> const &v)
  {
  std::ranges::transform(std::ranges::begin(u), std::ranges::end(u),
                         std::ranges::begin(v), std::ranges::end(v),
                         std::ranges::begin(u),
                         std::plus());
  }
  ```

```
        mov r8, QWORD PTR [rsi+8]
        mov rdx, QWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov rcx, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        cmp rdx, r8
        je .L1
        cmp rcx, rax
        jne .L3
        jmp .L1
        .L16:
        cmp rdx, r8
        je .L1
        .L3:
        movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax]
        addsd xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx]
        add rax, 8
        add rdx, 8
        movsd QWORD PTR [rax-8], xmm0
        cmp rax, rcx
        jne .L16
        .L1:
        ret
```

I can’t read assembly, but I seem to understand that the assemblies of Case 1 and Case 2 are almost equivalent and involve packed sums, whilst the assembly of the ranges versions (Cases 3 and 4) is much terser, but not vectorized.

I would really love to understand what those differences mean. Do my interpretation of the assembly make any sense? What are the additional instructions in the non-ranges versions? Why are there those differences?

Comment: The additional instructions care about head/tail elements of the arrays (vectors), which are either not aligned enough or there is not enough of them to be processed by SIMD instructions.

Comment: @DanielLangr Therefore the differences are due to the rangified versions not being vectorized, right? It seems extrange to me that the iterator version of `ranges::transform` didn't get vectorized because I expected it to perform the concept checking and then fall back to the legacy algorithm.

Comment: Yes, the ranged versions are not vectorized. You can easily distinguish both cases by observing the increments of `rax`, which is 16 in case of vectorization (size of `xmm` register) and 8 in non-vectorized versions (size of `double`).

Comment: I tried to use `-fopt-info-vec-missed` for GCC, and for Case 4, I got: `...cmcstl2/include/stl2/detail/algorithm/transform.hpp:61:33: missed: not vectorized: number of iterations cannot be computed`. You can see the source here: https://github.com/CaseyCarter/cmcstl2/blob/master/include/stl2/detail/algorithm/transform.hpp#L61. For some reason, it's not the case of `std::transform`, where this problem doesn't occur.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks! Maybe what makes the difference between `std::transform` and `ranges::transform` is that the latter takes into account the length of both vectors, while the former doesn't.

Comment: @DanielLangr. It seems that considering the size of both vectors prevents GCC from vectorizing the loop: https://godbolt.org/z/tdO5z6